# Facebook OG Tags in Meteor Not Working

Tags: html, meteor, share, facebook-opengraph, meta

I am using Meteor on the client side only and have been trying to optimise the open graph meta tags. I have used [`kadira:dochead`](https://github.com/kadirahq/meteor-dochead) and in the router put the following code:

```
Router.route('/', function() {
  setupOg();
  if (isMobile()) {
    this.render('landing_mobile');
    $('body').css("overflow", "visible");
  }
  else {
    this.render('landing');
    $('body').css("overflow", "hidden");
  }
});

function setupOg() {
  var title = { property: "og:title", content: "Blah" };
  var type = { property: "og:type", content: "website" };
  var url = { property: "og:url", content: "https://blah.io" };
  var image = { property: "og:image", content: "http://i63.tinypic.com/2howf4k.png" };
  var siteName = { property: "og:site_name", content: "Blah" };
  var description = { property: "blah blah blah." };

  DocHead.addMeta(title);
  DocHead.addMeta(type);
  DocHead.addMeta(url);
  DocHead.addMeta(image);
  DocHead.addMeta(siteName);
  DocHead.addMeta(description);
}
```

In the browser, upon inspecting the HEAD content, the contents are there as `<meta property="og:title" content="Blah" dochead="1">`, etc for each of the properties above.

However, when I look at the [Facebook Sharing Debugger](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/sharing), it does not seem to have found any of these optimisations, and when I try to share on Linkedin, same thing. Why is this?

Note, my `main.html` looks like this:

```
<head>
  <link rel="icon" sizes="16x16 32x32" href="/favicon.ico">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, height=device-height, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
  <title>Blah</title>
</head>
```

Comment: You should use prerendering lib or service as was already mentioned, some other links: [enhanced spiderable package](https://github.com/VeliovGroup/jazeee-meteor-spiderable), [prerendering with ES6 support](https://ostr.io/info/prerendering)

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 reasons I can distinguish:

1. Meteor has client side rendering, meaning that when Facebook opens the URL to analyse OG tags, it does not see any, so you need to tell Facebook bot that it needs to wait until your page is loaded, take a look at this Meteor package: https://atmospherejs.com/meteor/spiderable
2. Data for that URL may be cached.

Comment: And if you reeeeeally care about SEO you can use [prerender.io](https://prerender.io/) service